# Blocked packages problem in gentoo

Tags: linux, xfce, gentoo, emerge

I want to install xfce on gentoo but after running `root #emerge --ask xfce-base/xfce4-meta` there is error that the packages are blocked and i tried many things but none of them work. Please help me and thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the output of `emerge -pv xfce-base/xfce4-meta`? Without additional context it's difficult to know what the blockers are.

Comment: Did you solve this?  If so, you need to let us know.

Comment: @eyoung100 Yes i solved it